# Internal hyperlink in reStructuredText with customized text

Tags: syntax, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

I know how to create an external hyperlink with customized text.

```
`My cool link <http://www.asdf.com>`_
```

But I want to link to an internal reference.

```
.. _foo:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

So I'd like to do something like

```
`My cool internal link <foo>`_
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using reStructuredText with [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org), cross-reference other locations in the documentation with [the `ref` role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-ref):

```
:ref:`link text <link-target>`
```

The custom *link text* is optional if the referenced object defines a title or caption, as is the case for documents, sections, figures, etc. The target's title will then be used as the link text, but the angle brackets must be left out: `` :ref:`link-target` `` . The link text is mandatory when referencing paragraphs or images, as they don't have titles/captions associated with them.

The *link target* has to be defined somewhere in the documentation, possibly in other documents, i.e. `.rst` files. For sections, the extension [Autosectionlabel](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autosectionlabel.html) would do this automatically and the section's title then becomes the target, and thus also link text. In all other cases, [internal hyperlink targets](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#internal-hyperlink-targets) must be declared manually, for example like so:

```
.. _paragraph-to-be-linked-to:

This paragraph will be referenced from elsewhere in the documentation
with :ref:`that paragraph <paragraph-to-be-linked-to>`.
```

Note the leading underscore in the target definition. It [can be thought of as a right-pointing arrow](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-references), here pointing inward, toward the link target. We may also link to specific positions inside (long) paragraphs with [inline internal targets](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-internal-targets):

```
We want to point to _`this position` inside the paragraph
with :ref:`that paragraph <this position>` from elsewhere.
```

When using reStructuredText with [Docutils](https://docutils.sourceforge.io) alone, the `ref` role is not available, as it is a syntax extension added by Sphinx. Instead, we need the following syntax to create [hyperlinks](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-references):

```
`link text <link-target_>`_
```

Note the two trailing underscores, one after the link target and another after the full hyperlink. Here the imaginary arrows point outward.

Docutils only processes [standalone files](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/README.html#purpose). It is used by Sphinx as a back-end to parse individual reStructuredText source files. In Sphinx documentation, the latter syntax will therefore only work for internal links within the same document, but not across documents, i.e. a hyperlink defined in one `.rst` file referring to a target in another file.

Instead of the `ref` role, one may find [the `any` role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-any) provided by Sphinx even more convenient. It will additionally find link targets automatically created by extensions, such as for source code objects documented with [Autodoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html). When declared as the [default role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-default_role) in `conf.py`, with `default_role = 'any'`, we could then write `` `link text <link-target>` `` or even just `` `link-target` `` to create internal hyperlinks. Except for the absence of trailing underscores, the former looks much like the syntax for single-document reStructuredText as recognized by Docutils, but is processed by Sphinx in a cross-document manner.

Answer (score 17):

Solution:

```
`My cool internal link <foo_>`_
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't find my label with this solution (ERROR: Unknown target name)

Answer (score 11):

Use 2 underscores on text and 1 undescore on link target, example:

```
`My cool internal link <foo_>`__

... somewhere lower ...

.. _foo:

This staff is referenced by "My cool internal link"
```

When I use one underscore instead of 2, rst2pdf throws an error.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

If John's solution doesn't work for you:

```
`My cool internal link<foo>`
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have to use `my link <target_>` with a `_` after the last backtick. Also the link target doesn't work for headings unfortunately, only anchors. As a workaround I put `#my-heading-text` as the target and that works for HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You just needed to remove the space after your custom title, and before the angle brackets, and use the `:ref:` directive:

This works:

```
:ref:`My cool internal link with no space before bracket<foo>`
```

This doesn't:

```
:ref:`My cool internal link with space <foo>`
```