# How to reference a hyperlink by id in a reST text?

Tags: restructuredtext

I have the following reST text:

```
See this `example <https://example.org/1>`_ or this `example <https://example.org/2>`_.
```

But I don't want to use the embedded URI syntax because I found it less readable. What should I do for referencing my links?

```
See this `???`_ or this `???`_.

.. _exemple1: https://example.org/1
.. _exemple2: https://example.org/2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the response here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40555211/887855

```
See this `example <exemple1_>`__ or this `example <exemple2_>`__.

.. _exemple1: https://example.org/1
.. _exemple2: https://example.org/2
```